# Add Youku Player library in Android application

Tags: android, video-player, youku

I have to use Youku player library in my Android application and do everything which is needed.
Add `YoukuPlayerConfig` in my `Application` class

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        YoukuPlayerConfig.setLog(false);
        YoukuPlayerConfig.setClientIdAndSecret(CLIENT_ID_WITH_AD, CLIENT_SECRET_WITH_AD);
        YoukuPlayerConfig.onInitial(this);
    }
}
```

Add all permissions in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
```

But receive this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.randa.android-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.randa.android-1/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.android-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libnetcache.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:972)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1530)
        at com.youku.uplayer.NetCache.<clinit>(NetCache.java:17)
        at com.youku.uplayer.NetCache.SetUserAgent(Native Method)
        at com.youku.uplayer.PlayerNetCache.setUserAgent(PlayerNetCache.java:32)
        at com.youku.cloud.playercore.PlayerCoreManager.initNetCache(PlayerCoreManager.java:48)
        at com.youku.cloud.playercore.PlayerCoreManager.init(PlayerCoreManager.java:21)
        at com.youku.cloud.player.YoukuPlayerConfig.onInitial(YoukuPlayerConfig.java:44)
        at com.example.android.App.onCreate(App.java:43)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1024)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5361)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you check all the permission you add is enabled in the application settings? for example, reading and writing on external storage requires you to ask permission on devices android 5 and above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. YoukuPlayerOpenSDK-release.aar  only support armeabi-v7a.

> 1. gradle.properties file add this:  android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
> 2. build.gradle file setting ndk abiFilters:

```
   ndk {
      abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'// 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64', 'mips', 'mips64'
   }
```